# How do I restore two finger middle click again?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

it used to be that tapping two fingers on the touchpad send a middle mouse click. Now it does a right click and three fingers now are the middle click. I really can't understand the change and think it is a bug or badly copied from Apple or something. The reasoning escapes me totally.
I use middle click to open links in a new tab in the browser all day and I rarely use right click (and I have a right mouse button below the touchpad, doh)
Tapping three fingers on my tiny EeePC touchpad is next to impossible so I want the old behavior.
I found:

```
synclient TapButtons2=2
synclient TapButtons3=3
```

but that did not work on 10.10

Does anyone know how to restore sane behavior?

Comment: Should be TapButton2=2, etc., without the 's'.

Answer (score 10):

The default settings that seem to be enabled with "tap to click" (on my laptop anyway) also provides the following functionality:

- Middle Click (tap at top right of scroll area)
- Right Click (tap at bottom right of scroll area)

Comment: That's awesome. And it's working by default I never knew about it. Thank you. Great answer!

Comment: Works great, really hard one to guess.

Comment: This is not working if you enable "Two-finder scrolling". Two bad, because I like it more then "Edge scrolling".

Comment: Perfect it also works for ubuntu 18.04 with my new dell precision 5530

Answer (score 7):

You may also be interested in installing the [gpointing-device-settings](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpointing-device-settings) package, which will provide more configuration options for your touchpad. BTW, in Ubuntu 10.04LTS+ this replaces `gsynaptics`.

```
sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings
```

Once installed you find it under **System -> Preferences -> Pointing Devices**.

Answer (score 7):

The following solution has been tested on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10. It works perfectly.

1. Create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/touchpad.conf` with the following content:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
           Identifier      "Touchpad"                      # required
           MatchIsTouchpad "on"                           # required
           Driver          "synaptics"                     # required
           Option          "MinSpeed"              "0.5"
           Option          "MaxSpeed"              "1.0"
           Option          "AccelFactor"           "0.075"
           Option          "TapButton1"            "1"
           Option          "TapButton2"            "2"     # multitouch
           Option          "TapButton3"            "3"     # multitouch
           Option          "VertTwoFingerScroll"   "1"     # multitouch
           Option          "HorizTwoFingerScroll"  "1"     # multitouch
           Option          "VertEdgeScroll"        "1"
           Option          "CoastingSpeed"         "8"
           Option          "CornerCoasting"        "1"
           Option          "CircularScrolling"     "1"
           Option          "CircScrollTrigger"     "7"
           Option          "EdgeMotionUseAlways"   "1"
           Option          "LBCornerButton"        "8"     # browser "back" btn
           Option          "RBCornerButton"        "9"     # browser "forward" btn
   EndSection
   ```
2. Run `dconf-editor` from your user (don't sudo). Go to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.mouse`, uncheck `active`. *(It is a known issue that Gnome's Settings Daemon may override your `xorg.conf` settings).*
3. Log out and log in. Things should be working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

`xinput` gave:

> unable to find device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

so I did

```
synclient TapButton3=3 TapButton2=2
```

from a tip from http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1251372

I put this in my `~/.bashrc` and things seem to work

Answer (score 2):

To fix the middle click you can use the following command:

```
xinput set-int-prop NN 266 8 2 3 0 0 1 2 3
```

Where `NN` is the id of the mousepad device, you can see it with the command `xinput list`.
266 is the id of the property "Synaptics Tap Action" you can see it with `xinput list-props NN`

You have to run this command every time you boot/login/wake.

To make it permanent you can put this command to the end of your `.profile` file in your home folder. (You can also try to put it in `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, but in my case it didn't work.)

Comment: this is dangerous, please consider changing "266" to "PP" or so - the property number (266) is device dependent

Answer (score 2):

To preserve your synaptics configuration after resume, I followed this steps from wiki.archlinux.org:

> Gnome settings daemon may override existing settings (for example ones
>   set in xorg.conf.d) for which there is no equivalent in any of the
>   graphical configuration utilities. It is possible to stop gnome from
>   touching mouse settings at all:
>
> ```
> 1. Run dconf-editor
> 2. Edit /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/mouse/
> 3. Uncheck the active setting
> ```
>
> It will now respect your system's existing synaptics configuration.

It worked on Ubuntu 11.10 AND now I have:

- Two-finger scrolling.
- Middle Click with two fingers tap.
- Right Click (tap at bottom right of scroll area).

Answer (score 1):

Try running this as a script

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 8, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3  # pad corners rt rb lt lb tap fingers 1 2 3 (can't simulate more then 2 tap fingers AFAIK) - values: 0=disable 1=left 2=middle 3=right etc. (in FF 8=back 9=forward)
```

Comment: unable to find device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

Comment: xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 8, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3    works!

Answer (score 1):

OK,

I now have to run

```
xinput set-prop "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 8, 9, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3
```

and

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/suspend false
```

to restore things to something I can tolerate, BUT I have to run those commands after each resume.
Which script is run after each resume to automate that?

Comment: /etc/pm/sleep.d/99-test.sh    works for me

Comment: hmmm, it works for resume with out password but not for making double tap work

Comment: why is thid so hard?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "middle button emulation class"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
EndSection
```

**WARNING**:  try with caution.  When added to `~50-synaptics.conf` in 11.10,  may cause boot hang after login screen.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution #1

I just discovered that if you keep **two fingers pressed** on touchpad **and** press the **left click** "button" of the touchpad it emulates the middle mouse button (so you need 3 fingers in total)

#### Solution #2

If you still want to click both buttons and produce a middle button emulation, execute:

```
synclient EmulateMidButtonTime=100
```

**EmulateMidButtonTime** allows you to change the time required to produce a middle button (allowed time period to click both buttons). 100 means 100 milliseconds (ms).

You may set it to even higher values, such as `synclient EmulateMidButtonTime=500` for 500ms, which is enough time to click both buttons

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly what Nikita Volkov said (creating xorg.conf.d folder and touchpad.conf file), but my file looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "Touchpad"                      # required
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"                            # required
    Driver          "synaptics"                     # required
    Option          "MinSpeed"              "0.5"
    Option          "MaxSpeed"              "1.0"
    Option          "AccelFactor"           "0.075"
    Option          "TapButton1"            "1"
    Option          "TapButton2"            "2"     # multitouch
    Option          "TapButton3"            "3"     # multitouch
    Option          "VertTwoFingerScroll"   "1"     # multitouch
    Option          "HorizTwoFingerScroll"  "0"     # multitouch
    Option          "MaxTapTime"            "70"
    Option          "FastTaps"              "1"
EndSection
```

and now it's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

For me I lost two fingered right click after installing gnome. I tried several of these answers and this is what finally worked:

Try this:

`xinput --set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" --type=int "libinput Click Method Enabled" 0 1`

If it works, make it persist across reboots by adding it as a startup script.
Search for `Startup Application Preferences`.
`Add` a new Startup Program, and in `command`, paste the line from above.

[image]

Note: I previously tried adding it to `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` at first but that didn't work for me (gnome, ubuntu 16.10).

Answer (score -1):

```
synclient TapButton2=3 TapButton3=2
```

key named according to number of fingers, value indicates mouse button number.

Comment: Sorry, my original comment wasn't very useful. I confused this with a totally separate post. I apologize. Let me start again: If this method (which does not contain a typo, though the original question here does) is different from the method that the original question said **does not work**, you should edit this answer to explain how it is different. That is probably why this answer was downvoted. You should also edit this answer to explain what needs to be done in complete sentences, and to make clear `what parts of your answer are commands` and what parts are the explanation.